# PHP calculate cartesian product

Tags: php, cartesian-product

I am working on a layer that converts data from a multi dimensional array, into a mold to fit the legacy SQL tables.

The data looks like this

```
array(4) {
  "idnumber" =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "123456"
  }
  "names" =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "name1"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "name2"
  }
  "keycodes" =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(101)
    [1] =>
    int(102)
    [2] =>
    int(103)
  }
}
```

There can be any number of outer elements, and there can be any number of inner elements.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around a way to loop through them, and generate this (The keys don't matter, it's just my first vision of grouping these)

```
array() {
  "123456name1101" =>
  array(3){
    [0] =>
    string(6) "123456"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "name1"
    [2] =>
    int(101)
  }
  "123456name2101" =>
  array(3){
    [0] =>
    string(6) "123456"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "name2"
    [2] =>
    int(101)
  }
  "123456name1102" =>
  array(3){
    [0] =>
    string(6) "123456"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "name1"
    [2] =>
    int(102)
  }
  "123456name2102" =>
  array(3){
    [0] =>
    string(6) "123456"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "name2"
    [2] =>
    int(102)
  }
  "123456name1103" =>
  array(3){
    [0] =>
    string(6) "123456"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "name1"
    [2] =>
    int(103)
  }
  "123456name2103" =>
  array(3){
    [0] =>
    string(6) "123456"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "name2"
    [2] =>
    int(103)
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but wouldn't it be easier to represent a result set as an array/list of arrays?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not sure I follow

Comment: Do you need a cross product of the 3 inner arrays?

Comment: @apokryfos Never heard of a cross product before, but your answer looks pretty good

Comment: It's also known as a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you, that appears to be exactly what I needed.  Big thank you for answering my question that asked the wrong question.  I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that calculates the cross product. This is not my code, I found it somewhere online a few years ago and have been using it since. I can't remember where it's from.

```
function crossProduct($array1=[], $array2=[], $_=[]) {
    $_ = func_get_args();
    if (count($_) == 0) {
        return array(array());
    }
    $a = array_shift($_);
    $c = call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $_);
    $r = array();
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        foreach ($c as $p) {
            $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
        }
    }
    return $r;
}


$array = array(
  "idnumber" => array("123456"),
  "names" => array("name1", "name2"),
  "keycodes" => array(101, 102, 103)
);

$result = crossProduct($array["idnumber"], $array["names"], $array["keycodes"]);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => name1
            [2] => 101
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => name1
            [2] => 102
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => name1
            [2] => 103
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => name2
            [2] => 101
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => name2
            [2] => 102
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => name2
            [2] => 103
        )

)
```

Comment: Are $array1=[], $array2=[] passed in and not used?

Comment: No, the main reason for the explicit arguments is for IDE typehinting. The arguments are actually read from `$_ = func_get_args();`

Comment: A quick change, It can also be invoked like this `$result=call_user_func_array('crossProduct', $array);` so it works without knowing how many array items you have so it can be truly generic.  I don't know how many outer array elements I will have, so I need it generic like this.